# How to change the background color registry and update desktop immediatly?

Tags: registry, background-color

I want to change the background color!
So i change the registry: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Colors
and in order for the desktop to refresh with the new color, i must restart computer and change one time the desktop background..

How can i avoid the restart thing?

Because the default windows app. changes the registry as well, but somehow updates the color immediatly on the desktop..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found the solution :)

Here you go if anyone ever needs it

```
int aElements[1] = {COLOR_BACKGROUND};
DWORD aNewColors[1];
aNewColors[0] = RGB(0x80, 0x00, 0x80);  // dark purple
SetSysColors(1, aElements, aNewColors);
```

Comment: So, what. Is this a script (batch file)? Do you type these commands in a CMD prompt? Maybe this is a C program? A bit more info is needed here please.

Comment: Unhelpful--no language context.

Comment: Language is C++, using Windows function "SetSysColors": https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setsyscolors

Comment: This answer is not complete without a procedure for how to use the code it contains.